# Multiply entire columns with values in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a very large dataframe and would like to multiply every element in each column with a value in a list.

```
       Name  c1  c2  c3  c4
    0   a1   1   2   2   3
    1   a2   2   1   1   2
    2   a3   3   1   2   1
    3   a4   2   3   3   4
```

`l = [2, 3, 1, 4]`

What I would like to do is multiply the entire column c1 with 2, c2 with 3, c3 with 1, c4 with 3 and so on.

I know that I can do it for one column with
    `df.iloc[:,0] = df.iloc[:,0]*2`
but I am unsure of how to do it efficiently over all the columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.loc` and column names in the following way:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(12)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "df0" : np.random.choice(["a", "b"], 100),
        "df1" : np.random.randint(0, 15, 100), 
        "df2" : np.random.randint(0, 15, 100),
        "df3" : np.random.randint(0, 15, 100),
        "df4" : np.random.randint(0, 15, 100),
    }
)
print(df.head())

l = [2, 3, 1, 4]
df.loc[:, ["df1", "df2", "df3", "df4"]] *= np.array(l)

df.head()
```

Here is the output:

```
  df0  df1  df2  df3  df4
0   b    5   10    7   13
1   b    3    2   13    3
2   a    5    0   11   14
3   b   11    1    7   10
4   b    0    4    1   12

  df0  df1  df2  df3  df4
0   b   10   30    7   52
1   b    6    6   13   12
2   a   10    0   11   56
3   b   22    3    7   40
4   b    0   12    1   48
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you were doing correct you need to define all columns you need to multiply

```
df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:]*l
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and multiple all columns without first:

```
l = [2, 3, 1, 4]
df.iloc[:, 1:] *= l
print (df)
  Name  c1  c2  c3  c4
0   a1   2   6   2  12
1   a2   4   3   1   8
2   a3   6   3   2   4
3   a4   4   9   3  16
```